# mediation analysis in R with multiple imputation (MICE), standardized coefficients

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I need to conduct a **mediation analysis in R** with **incomplete data** for my master's thesis. For the **missings** I use **MICE multiple imputation** according to van Buuren & Groothuis-Oudshoorn (2011).

For the mediation analysis I have considered to refer to **Tingley et al. (2014;** https://oar.princeton.edu/jspui/bitstream/88435/pr1gj2f/1/Mediation%20JSS.pdf)

Here, you can find his code: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mediation/mediation.pdf
Hypothetical example
To use mediations, must make list of multiple datasets. Then, must also repeat the treatment assignment list as many times as you have data sets.

```
datasets <- list(D1=D1, D2=D2) # list of multiply imputed data sets
mediators <- c("M1")
outcome <- c("Ycont1")
treatment <- c("T1","T1") # note how the treatment indicator is repeated
covariates <- c("X1+X2")
olsols <- mediations(datasets, treatment, mediators, outcome, covariates,
    families=c("gaussian","gaussian"), interaction=FALSE, conf.level=.90, sims=1000)
output <- amelidiate(olsols) # summary(output)
plot(output)
```

For my master thesis I want to find out if the therapeutic alliance between an eCoach and a patient mediates the relationship of the number of completed modules of an internet-based depression intervention and the severity of depression.

Number of completed modules (ModuleEr) -> therapeutic alliance (WAI_C) -> severity of depression (QIDS_t1)

My variables are numeric. I am especially **interested in the standardized coefficients**.I tried Tingley’s Code aswell and adapted to my variables:

```
df <-data
library(mice)
library(mediation)
```

simple imputation for testing reasons

```
imp <- mice(df, m=5, seed = 1234)
```

I convert every imputed data set

```
imp1 <- complete(imp,1)
imp2 <- complete(imp,2)
imp3 <- complete(imp,3)
imp4 <- complete(imp,4)
imp5 <- complete(imp,5)
```

I standardize my data sets, only numeric variables

```
imp1z <- scale(imp1[,1:13])
imp2z <- scale(imp2[,1:13])
imp3z <- scale(imp3[,1:13])
imp4z <- scale(imp4[,1:13])
imp5z <- scale(imp5[,1:13])
```

I make two lists of multiply imputed data sets: one list with standardized variables, one with unstandardized variables

```
datasets1 <- list(imp1=imp1, imp2=imp2, imp3=imp3, imp4=imp4, imp5=imp5)
datasets2<- list(imp1z=imp1z, imp2z=imp2z, imp3z=imp3z, imp4z=imp4z, imp5z=imp5z)
```

then I define my mediator, outcome, treatment an covarites

```
mediators <- c("WAI_C")
outcome <- c("QIDS_t1")
treatment <- c("ModuleEr", "ModuleEr", "ModuleEr", "ModuleEr", "ModuleEr" ) # is it correct to repeat the treatment as many times as you have data sets? I hav read it here: https://rdrr.io/cran/mediation/src/R/amelidiate.R
covariates <- c("QIDS_t0")
```

next I use the mediations function with unstandardized variables. I was wondering how to define the families=c("gaussian","gaussian“). My variables are not normally distributed…

```
olsols1 <- mediations(datasets1, treatment, mediators, outcome, covariates, interaction=FALSE, conf.level=.95, sims=10)
output1 <- amelidiate(olsols1)
summary(output1)
plot(output1) # the plot function doesn’t work: Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

My output 1 looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVZcA.png)
If I repeat the mediations function with the standardized data sets (datasets2), I I get error messages:

```
olsols2 <- mediations(datasets2, treatment, mediators, outcome, covariates, interaction=FALSE, conf.level=.95, sims=10)
output2 <- amelidiate(olsols2)
summary(output2)
```

*Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : Object 'WAI_C' not found*
*Additional: Warning:*
*In dataarg$weight <- weight <- rep(1, nrow(dataarg)) :*
*Convert left side to a list*

What is wrong? Why can WAI_C not been found? I checked all 5 standardized data sets, they all include WAI_C. Why is especially the mediator variable affected?

And how can I convert left side to a list?

Since the output1 only shows ACME,ADE, total Effect.. How do I obtain the associated regression coefficients? Is it enough to simply set up the regression equations?

```
Med1 <- with(data = imp, exp = lm(scale(WAI_C) ~ scale(ModuleEr) + scale(QIDS_t0)))
Med1.pooled <- pool(Med1)
summary(Med1.pooled)

Med2 <- with(data = imp, exp = lm(scale(QIDS_t1) ~ scale(ModuleEr) + scale(WAI_P) + scale(QIDS_t0)))
Med2.pooled <- pool(Med2)
summary(Med2.pooled)
```

Comment: Hi, have you looked into non-parametric imputation methods? You could try the [missForest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/missForest/index.html) package, which gives you just one single imputed dataset, and could make live easier. Here a comparison of parametric and non-parametric imputation methods: https://jmlr.org/papers/volume18/17-073/17-073.pdf

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you don't need to use `c()` when you're storing a vector of length 1 (e.g. `mediators <- c("M1")`). You can just do `mediators <- "M1"`.